# Error in third party Library addition in qt android project

Tags: android, qt-necessitas

I am trying to add and android library to my qt android project. But it fails while deploying.
I followed steps as given in documentation : [Third-party Android Libraries](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/android3rdpartylibs.html)

I get the error

> BUILD FAILED
>   E:\Installations\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:577:
>   ../android-build/libs/ resolve to a path with no project.properties
>   file for project
>   E:\WorkSpaces\Qt\Qt_WidgetApps\AndroidSerialPortTrials\ThirdPartyLib\build-ThirdPartyLib-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_0_Android_GCC_arm_4_8-Debug\android-build

my project.properties

```
android.library.reference.1=../android-build/libs/
```

projectPath/android/

- libs/
- AndroidManifest.xml
- project.properties

projectPath/android/libs/
 - xx.so 
 - yy.jar

I tried

```
android.library.reference.1=libs/ as given in documentation
android.library.reference.1=../android/libs/
android.library.reference.1=./libs/
```

But all gives error